# Generic Echo Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to make an echo web service that replies back with the request content, regardless of what that content is.  Just an endpoint listening for anything and spitting it back.

So for example if it is called with "hi", the response content is "hi".  If it is called with a multi-part message containing a form data, the data comes back.  If it is a JSON message then JSON comes back.  This is regardless of what the actual content is or what url parameters are provided.  Basically I want it to send the same thing back regardless of the mime type, don't try to interpret it, just spit it back.

I'm starting with the following:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    private interface IEchoService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        object Echo(object s);
    }

    private class EchoService : IEchoService
    {
        public object Echo(object s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
```

---

```
 WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(EchoService), new Uri("http://localhost:8002/"));
 WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
 ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEchoService), binding, "echo");
```

Any ideas how to make this work?  This just returns back a HTTP status code of bad request when called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is to use the System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message class.

```
    [ServiceContract]
    private interface IEchoService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        Message Echo(Message s);
    }

    private class EchoService : IEchoService
    {
        public Message Echo(Message s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
```